# Cannot find module gulp.js when publishing to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2015, npm, gulp

I've got a website project in Visual Studio based on the MVC5 project template and published it successfully to Azure continuously.

Since I moved my TFVC workspace from one drive (C:) to another and (Z:) by creating a new workspace and getting latest from source control I got publishing issues:

> module.js:327
>   at node.js:999:3
>   The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 1.
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
>   ^
>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:429:10)
>   at startup (node.js:139:18)
>   throw err;
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
>   Cannot find module 'Z:...Website\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'

[image]

My prepublish commands in the *project.json* file:

```
"prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
```

After hours of updating extensions and packages, and running npm commands, I'm lost. Any hint to solve this issue would be appreciated.

I followed this SO question [Node.js error in Azure build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158159/node-js-error-in-azure-build) and changed my prepublish command to this:

```
"prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install" ]
```

That allowed me to publish again, but I'd like to run the gulp commands before publishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 options you can follow to try:

1. Install `gulp` globally via `npm install -g gulp`, then the MS build run the tasks in `prepublish` will use the global `gulp` modules.
2. Leverage local `gulp` tool path. After executing `npm install`, it should install the node.js modules in the `node_modules` folder in the same directory with `project.json`. You can try to modify the gulp commands to `"node_modules/.bin/gulp clean"` and `"node_modules/.bin/gulp min"` to use local gulp tool's path to execute the command.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.